# Rails - nested form not saving my records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

With my model:

```
class Lab < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :business_days, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :business_days, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['kind'].blank?}
    # ...
end
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @lab = Lab
    7.times { @lab.business_days.build}
end
```

I created a form to save my lab record to the database. I wanted to save available business days in one shot so I added this:

```
<table class="table table-default">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <% @weekdays.each do |day| %>
          <th class="text-center"><%= day[0..2].capitalize %></th>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="vertical-align: middle;">From:</th>
        <% @lab.business_days.each.with_index do |bd, index| %>
          <%= f.fields_for :business_days_attributes, index: index do |bd_form| %>
            <%= bd_form.hidden_field :day, value: @weekdays[index] %>
            <td><%= bd_form.text_field :from_time %></td>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="vertical-align: middle;">To:</th>
        <% @lab.business_days.each.with_index do |bd, index| %>
          <%= f.fields_for :business_days_attributes, index: index do |bd_form| %>
            <td><%= bd_form.text_field :to_time %></td>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and what it does is explained in the picture:

[image: business_day_table]

My create action looks like this:

```
def create
    @lab = Lab.new(lab_params)
    if @lab.save
end
```

And lab_params definition looks like this:

```
def lab_params
    return params.require(:lab).permit(:name, :street, :city, :postal_code, :state, :country, business_days_attributes: [:day, :from_time, :to_time])
end
```

My problem is when I save try to submit the form the Lab record gets saved but no BusinessDay records is created/ saved.

My question is - where did I make a mistake?

**EDIT - params as requested:**

```
Started POST "/labs" for ::1 at 2016-09-19 17:15:40 +0200
Processing by LabsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sbiXra6IQBpleuCqZ+zUFN+mDAzjSa/b9VgCYz6kL2VyeTkiqcldy5SOVXJCHr3HrWbUMCjtlBUrjXOBrWOhHA==", "lab"=>{"name"=>"Laboratory Uno", "street"=>"some street", "city"=>"some city", "business_days_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"day"=>"monday", "from_time"=>"00:00", "to_time"=>"15:00"}, "1"=>{"day"=>"tuesday", "from_time"=>"", "to_time"=>""}, "2"=>{"day"=>"wednesday", "from_time"=>"", "to_time"=>""}, "3"=>{"day"=>"thursday", "from_time"=>"", "to_time"=>""}, "4"=>{"day"=>"friday", "from_time"=>"", "to_time"=>""}, "5"=>{"day"=>"saturday", "from_time"=>"", "to_time"=>""}, "6"=>{"day"=>"sunday", "from_time"=>"", "to_time"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Add to database"}
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "labs" ("name", "street", "city", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Laboratory Uno"], ["street", "some street"], ["city", "some city"], ["created_at", 2016-09-19 15:15:40 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-09-19 15:15:40 UTC]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/labs/7
Completed 302 Found in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

**Edit 2 - after removing `reject if`**

```
...params...
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
...redirect
```

**Edit 3 - saving from controller with bang**
What I did is add an "!" do my controller:

```
@lab = Lab.new(lab_params)
    if @lab.save!
....
```

And the result is this error:

**Validation failed: Business days lab must exist**

So it seems that the Lab record is not saved and that is why business days can't be created, right?

Comment: show the error log from your terminal

Comment: Can you include from the console the params that are being sent to the create action?

Comment: Parameters included. No error is displayed.

Comment: isn't `kind` always blank ?, perhaps that's what's preventing your records from being saved.

Comment: Removed the reject if statement. Edit included

Comment: After each `f.fields_for` try just `:business_days` instead of `:business_days_attributes`

Comment: I was trying to do this but then it renders 7 times more textfields. Removing .each loop fixes that but the result in input name is the same as it was before. What's more is after doing this creating second fields_for starts counting from lab[:business_days_attributes][8] and not from 0.

Comment: still, even if you had other problems with the textfields, did using `business_days` allow the business_days attributes to be saved properly?

Comment: No it did not, there was still "rollback" error.

Comment: Added new edit. Hope this will clarify

Answer (score 0):

Your strong params are not accepting your identifier for your days. Instead of this:

```
def lab_params
  return params.require(:lab).permit(:name, :street, :city, :postal_code, :state, :country, business_days_attributes: [:day, :from_time, :to_time])
end
```

Use this:

```
def lab_params
  return params.require(:lab).permit(:name, :street, :city, :postal_code, :state, :country, business_days_attributes: [:business_day_id, :day, :from_time, :to_time])
end
```

or

```
def lab_params
  return params.require(:lab).permit(:name, :street, :city, :postal_code, :state, :country, business_days_attributes: [:id, :day, :from_time, :to_time])
end
```

Comment: I was trying to do this, but still, the rollback exists and the records are not saved

Comment: Do you have any validations?

Comment: Not at this moment. I turned all of them off. I am wondering if there is a way for fields_for to pass empty array as index, so the name of the input would look like: place[business_days_attributes][][from_time]?

Comment: Passing nil to index created the params like described above, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

And I got it.
The problem was probably with the lab not being saved before the business day.

Based on docs [website](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-Validating+the+presence+of+a+parent+model) all I needed was to add a couple of lines of code. Now everything works as it supposed! Thanks anyways guys!